# Reading string values from csv

Tags: python, pandas

```
+-----------+-------+-----------------------+
|V1         |   n   | ip                    |
+-----------+-------+-----------------------+
|02-08-2017 |2      |00.121.187.120:3447    |
|03-08-2017 |5      |01.110.186.182:23      |
|30-07-2017 |13     |08.167.141.192:25      |
|26-07-2017 |19     |1.175.4.214:33274      |
|01-08-2017 |72     |10.174.218.134:59259   |
+-----------+-------+-----------------------+
```

This is my csv file, I am trying to use a clustering technique but my column "V1" is saved as string hence i am not able to read it.

```
import pandas
import pylab as pl

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import ast


variables = pandas.read_csv('D:\\Date\\date-dfki.csv',dtype=str)

Y =  variables[['V1']]

X = variables[['n']]
Nc = range(1, 20)

kmeans = [KMeans(n_clusters=i) for i in Nc]
```

kmeans

```
score = [kmeans[i].fit(Y).score(Y) for i in range(len(kmeans))]
```

score

```
pl.plot(Nc,score)

pl.xlabel('Number of Clusters')

pl.ylabel('Score')

pl.title('Elbow Curve')
```

Please can someone tell me how to do read it as i cannot covert the string to float/int i am not able to proceed as well.
This is the error i am getting:

```
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
**ValueError: could not convert string to float: '27-07-2017'**
```

Comment: how you want to read the IP address ? because is not in ipv4 or ipv6 format ... the way you listed can be used as str.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> listing here an example for what can be done.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create dataset sample
d = {'V1': ["02-08-2017" , "03-08-2017"], 'n': ["2", "5"],'ip': ["104.44.194.237:25", "106.42.34.86:49324 "] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, dtype=np.int8)
df.to_csv('date-dfki.csv', sep=',')


#here from where starts your read file:
parse_dates = ['V1'] #specify the column you need for datetime, because on read pandas automatically read the date as string. 
variables = pd.read_csv('date-dfki.csv', dtype={'V1': str, 'ip': np.str, 'n': np.int32}, parse_dates=parse_dates) #in data type you specify each column what format to use
```

variables dataset:

[image: example dataset]

> Next, you need to clear the IP address so you can convert in int or float or any other format you want(I used int):

```
variables['ip'] = variables['ip'].str.replace('.', '') #removes '.'
variables['ip'] = variables['ip'].str.replace(':', '') #removes ':'
variables['ip'] = variables['ip'].astype(int) #convert to 'int'
```

with the results as follow:

[image: result conversion]

So if you have multiple columns you can do same process for each and convert in any format you want.

> Here is the float conversion:

```
variables['ip'] = variables['ip'].astype(float) #or float conversion
```

[image: float conversion]

Comment: Thank you would try them with my data and check how it works.

Comment: @BinduNagendra if you find the answers helpful, please do not forget to accept the answer or up-vote the effort of the users helping you.

Comment: @HarvIpan, the OP looks for a read of the data in this type of format, your downvote doesn’t make sense, is even IP conversion module, ipaddress, that takes ip and convert to int but the sample data is not fitting the ipv4 or ipv6 format. The answer is about the read about the data with multiple format and doesn’t look for a way of “correct” calculations.

Comment: The problem here is not: ”how I use IPs in modeling?” ... I’m not looking to enforce the correctness of the model(this is not the scope of the question), the OP can ultimately convert as factor or split (doing feature engineering) ... problem the OP dealing is the reading data in multiple format and convert to required OPs project needs (pandas store as objects).